# AlertDialog crashed after DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, datepickerdialog

All Hi!

If I show DatePickerDialog and click button negative, next I want show AlertDialog but he crashed. If I show DatePickerDialog and click button_positive - then all is well (AlertDialog can show).

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        if (id == DIALOG_DATE) {
            final DatePickerDialog tpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, myCallBack, 2000, 02, 02);
            tpd.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Button d = tpd.getButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                    d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            tpd.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return tpd;
        }
        if (id == DIALOG_ABOUT) {
            final LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.dialog_about, null);
            final AlertDialog adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setView(view)
                    .setTitle("О программе")
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.next,
                            new Dialog.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which) {
                                    // Do nothing here. We override the onclick
                                }
                            }).create();

            adb.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

                public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {

                    Button b = adb.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            adb.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return adb;

        }
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
```

> 08-29 08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-29
>   08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454): java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.app.AlertDialog 08-29 08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):    at
>   ru.pososhok.app.stp1.onPrepareDialog(stp1.java:421) 08-29
>   08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at
>   android.app.Activity.onPrepareDialog(Activity.java:2515) 08-29
>   08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at
>   android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2565) 08-29
>   08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at
>   android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2524) 08-29
>   08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at
>   ru.pososhok.app.menu.onOptionsItemSelected(menu.java:36) 08-29
>   08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at
>   android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2205) 08-29
>   08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:748)
>   08-29 08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):    at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
>   08-29 08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):    at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
>   08-29 08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):    at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
>   08-29 08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):    at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
>   08-29 08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):    at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080) 08-29 08:18:12.080:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(454):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 08-29
>   08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 08-29
>   08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 08-29 08:18:12.080:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(454):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 08-29
>   08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-29
>   08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 08-29 08:18:12.080:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(454):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   08-29 08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 08-29
>   08:18:12.080: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: what is at stp1.java line 421?

Comment: can you show OnprepareDailog code

Comment: Big thx! Real problem be in onPrepareDialog code. line 421 is onPrepareDialog) There was be no verification "updateDate" function